# Using SmartTarget with mobile app

Tags: web8, content-delivery, experience-optimization, microservices

We need expert advice on providing solution approach for building a Mobile app with integration to SDL Tridion.  Requirement is to build a Mobile App which will pull the content from content data store.  The content must be displayed based on enduser's interest using SmartTarget (Experience Optimization).

1. Is there any Out of the Box (OOTB) microservice which will provide data to mobile app based on request parameters?
2. We have to build custom API or REST service which will provide the output in JSON, XML or any other format.
3. Is there any need to use Tridion delivery jars in mobile app as well, to get content from Microservices?

Comment: In my experience, you're better off creating your own REST layer which exposes YOUR domain/data model for your app, and have this layer have the connection to Tridion. 2 main reasons: 1: complete control on API and response "weight", 2: Ability to include more data from non-Tridion sources in the same response.

Answer (score 4):

The Content Delivery microservices are currently only accessible through the [CIL](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-81392091-336E-422E-A8ED-247E397FE947) (as explained here http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-A2A47810-D27A-40CA-8C22-CCDC224AF81C), which means that you will have to use the SDL Web Content Delivery API, and thus its jars or assemblies (available via Maven or NuGet) in your mobile application.

If you can't do that (because for instance your mobile application is not written in Java or .NET), you will indeed have to create your own REST layer.

Comment: Also a point that I missed in the question is we are using TridionMVC framework designed especially for our client by SDL itself,  we need to investigate if XO will work with TridionMVC framework or not.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use XO features in the mobileApp and already using DXA, there is an OOTB option available,

Create a mobile page in Tridion and publish it to dxa webapp. Use DXA webapp to generate json response and consume it in the mobile app (eg: http://mydxawebapp.com?format=json).

In that way you can achieve all the XO features OOTB from tridion and personlised promotions in the mobile app irrespective of the technology you use to create the mobileApp (i.e., be it Android, IOS, Ionic, Cordova, etc.,)

I know there is an additional overhead in rerouting the json response from the webapp rather than directly consuming it via Content Microservice, but that will just do the trick.

Happy coding!

Comment: Very good solution, using DXA as a (micro)service will indeed deliver a very quick out of the box result. @user1453602 I recommend considering this.